# how to easily create an class object without knowing exactly what's the class type

Tags: c++

Let's say i have a base class `Base`, and two derived class`A,B`
How can i dynamically create a `obj`, without knowing if its `ClassA` or `ClassB`, i need to achieve such things like that:

```
func(Base &b)
{
X *obj = new X();
}
```

X would be A or B, depends on the actual Type of b.

The only way i can think of so far is to check if `dynamic_cast<A&>(b)` succeed or not, if an error is thrown, it must be a ClassB.

Is there a better way than that? because i may have more derived classes.ClassA,B,C,D...

Comment: You don't use the `virtual` keyword often enough.

Comment: @enryyao You can declare a virtual function create in the base class.

Comment: define the interface function as  `virtual`, then you can use pointer to base class directly.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow correct my if i'm wrong. So i create a virtual function in the Base and derived Classes. This function takes care of generating a new obj and return the pointer to that new obj? And i can call the correct virtual function through parameter b. Is that right?

Comment: @henryyao You are right. Moreover for each derived class the function will have the return type that is the type of the pointer to the derived class.